# Why my Task.Run() has not been executed in console application?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task, console-application

I've been struggling with a console application that I retrieve from another developer.
The client need a console application that run asynchronously to acknowledge the execution for the caller (with a line printed in console I guess) and having the script run afterward.

```cs
        static int batchId = 0;
        static int requestId = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#if DEBUG
            while (true)
            {
                // This method set our 2 var up above with value typed in the console. It's only for testing purpose
                GetKeyTappedBis();
                if (batchId > 0 && requestId > 0) break;
            }
#else
            SetArguments(args);
#endif
            ServiceProviderFactory.ServiceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                // ...
                .BuildServiceProvider();
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Batch n°{batchId} will be executed.");
                await Application.Run(batchId, requestId);
            });
        }
```

I may have some trouble understanding async execution. But I really don't understand why with this piece of code, when I try to debug it, I cannot enter in the `Application.Run()` execution. Unless I insert `Console.ReadLine()` after the `Task.Run()` which then will execute my method.

I didn't find any help before asking this question.

Comment: `Task.Run` only runs(doesn't wait till finished) task so what is you expected ?

Comment: Can you not just make the main method an async `Task`? Then remove `Task.Run`, and simply just call `await Application.Run(batchId, requestId);`

Comment: Change the signature to `static async Task Main(...)` and use `await Task.Run(...)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Why use `Task.Run` at all? Just get rid of it and simply `await Application.Run(...);`

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway? Why do you need to call `Application.Run` in *another* thread when you can keep working on the main thread? This just wastes the main thread

Comment: I just got into the code few hours ago with some vague instructions from the previous developer. From what I understood, the purpose of this code was to send a acknowledge response to the caller while the code was running (so an action had to follow my `Application.Run()`, which did not here. I just asked and it was an incomplete POC. Now, I know why I was confused. I will remove the Task.Run() and re-evaluate the need that has change since the first spec. Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to await the `Task` otherwise the thread will probably terminate before running the Task. Mixing asynchronous code in synchronous code is seen as a bad practice (this could lead to deadlocks for example).

To avoid this from happening you should consider a couple of things.

- "Can I make the method asynchronous"
- "What is the impact of making my method asynchronous"

Once you have made a decision if you can make your method async. Which in your case is the way to go. You should start looking at how you can avoid running the Task.

The first step should be making the method async:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
```

*As of Visual Studio 2017 Update 3 (15.3), the language now supports an async Main - as long as it returns Task or Task*

Secondly re-evaluating your code:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Batch n°{batchId} will be executed.");
    await Application.Run(batchId, requestId);
});
```

We now know that we can run `Application.Run()` in the same thread as the main method, since it is both async and there are no reasons why it should be run separately. So simply Await `Application.Run()`:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Batch n°{batchId} will be executed.");
await Application.Run(batchId, requestId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just gave few information I receive since my post and indeed, there was no need for another thread. I will change and take your advice :)

Answer (score 3):

You would wave to await it! If you do not await it, your main thread will terminate without having executed your async Task:

```
await Task.Run(....);
```

Comment: Do not forget to change the main method to an async `Task`, a method of type `void` is not awaitable